# Android: action overflow icon blue underline

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to remove the blue underline in the action bar overflow icon. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I don't have tabs but I saw some similar answered questions about action bar tabs underline but nothing worked for me. My Base application theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light. Here are the applied styles:

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/nav_drawer_selection</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/nav_drawer_selection</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="OverFlow"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Thanks for all the help! If you need more info about the app and code let me know :)

Comment: do you have a tab or something there?

Comment: Nope. I don't have them.

Comment: Post any styles you have relating to the `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around and I found out that it's a very easy solution. I added `<item name="android:background">@color/red</item>` to `<style name="OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">`

Answer (score 1):

@nejc.m i think it's due to inheritance from the "Widget" parent.  Try replacing "Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar" with "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar".  Let me know if this works.

Comment: It made my ActionBar disappear.

Comment: @nejc.m  Interesting. That's the fix that I did in mine.  Anyway, what I found out in my case was that the "Widget" parent had some default properties which included the blue line.  I suggest trying another parent source, like "Theme.AppCompat.Light" or "Theme.AppCompat" or something else.

Comment: Thank you. I will play around and post the results :)

Comment: I played around and I found out that it's a very easy solution. I added `<item name="android:background">@color/red</item>` to `<style name="OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">`